# Add a specifc value as a new dimension of a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape (224,224,3) after reading a image. However I would like to convert this into a shape of (4,224,224,3).

I would like to kind of repeat the same values.

I am trying to append like shown below this but it doesn't work.

```
np.append(image,[[[4]]],axis=1)
```

Instead it throws the below error

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I expect my output shape to be (4,224,224,3)

Can you guide me on how to do this?

Comment: you explain the shape but not the array itself. Along your new dimension, each "subarray" has shape (224,224,3) again. What do you want inside this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.repeat.html) setting axis to `0`:

```
out = np.repeat([image], 4, axis=0)
out.shape
# (4, 224, 224, 3)
```